# Error while add Category or Tag in Wordpress

Tags: categories, tags, dashboard

When I want to create a new category or tag on the Wordpress site. I encountered this error.

Empty Term.

As usual,
My theme and Plugins are updated.
I disabled all plugins. The error was not resolved.
I replaced all the Wordpress files and folders with a new version and it didn't fix the problem.
I repaired and optimized the database tables and the error was not fixed.
I could not disable the theme (enfold)because the site is working.

If you have experienced this error, please help me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Rename the "plugins" folder in "wp-content" and create a new empty "plugins" folder. Test if the error persists.

Temporarily revert any custom code or modifications in your theme.

Add a higher memory limit to "wp-config.php."

Use the "WP-Optimize" plugin to optimize and repair the database.

Check for error messages by enabling WordPress debugging in "wp-config.php."

Reach out to the "Enfold" theme support team for assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Category tables damaged. Delete wp_terms table and insert them again and problem is solved.